# How to uninstall domain controller role from server with command prompt

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows

I have the following problem:
I need to create a test Win Server 2008 R2 as Virtual machine, and set active directory on it. Never did this before, so I just experimenting. 
The problem is, after I installed the server, then I set is as domain controller using the wizard, but I messed something and now I cannot login to my server anymore (it is already set as domain controller). The local password is not recognized when I try to login.
I want to revert to before installing domain cont which rol role, I was able to boot in recovery console, but there I have only System Restore from image file (and I don't havce image file) and comand prompt
Does anyone knows how can I uninstall domain controller role (and eventually DNS server role, which was installed at the same time) using command prompt, so I can login with my local password?
Or maybe a way to reset domain password so I can login in my server normally?

Thank you

(hope I was clear enough, I'm not sysadmin, just developer and I need to install / config this to have access to a test machine with AD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a virtual machine, and you have only just installed Active Directory I would guess the server has nothing important on it yet. If this is the case, I think you'll be better off just nuking the virtual machine and starting again.

Before you nuke it though, just try one thing. Did you change the regional settings (specifically the keyboard) between the time you set the password and rebooted? This frequently trips me up when the password has a special character which is on different keys on a US and UK keyboard (for example the `#` button on a UK keyboard with US keyboard settings is a `\`).

If you have changed the keyboard settings and your password contains special characters, type the password in the username box so you can see what you're typing. You'll probably have to press random symbol buttons until you get the special character you're after. When you're in Windows with the correct keyboard layout, change the password to what it should be.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but not, my pass didn't contains any special character, and the key layout is the same. I thought to start all over again, but I'm just thinking, if I faced this situation, maybe I can learn something new and find a way to regain access to it.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but I am not going to help you regain access. Here at Server Fault, we frown on suggesting ways of what is effectively hacking into a machine.

Comment: Don't worry. However, this isn't any hacking, since it's my test machine. But after founding some more info on AD and DNS planning and configuration, I realize I did some wrong choices when I initially installed it, so I'll start all over again. Thanks for your suggestions anyway